# sql select query issue

Tags: sql-server

i have an values in temp table like this

```
ID
1
2
3
```

but know  from employee  table i need  to select values based from temp table

```
declare  @mStrvalue as varchar(100)
select   @mStrvalue =IDS from Temp_ID
select * from employee where employee.emp_ID= @mStrvalue
```

Right now this staement is giving me only 1 row value actually there is data present for  all the ids

is there anything wrong in th e syntax that i am going, pls let me know.

thnkas 
prince

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
select * from employee where employee.emp_ID in (select IDS from Temp_ID);
```

Or you could just join the two tables.

```
select *
  from employee inner join Temp_ID on employee.id = Temp_ID.IDS;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just join?

```
SELECT 
   *
FROM employee 
   INNER JOIN Temp_ID ON employee.emp_ID = Temp_ID.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to join the temp table with the employee table:

```
    select e.*
      from employee e
inner join Temp_ID t on e.emp_id = t.ids
```

This should return only employees whose id's are in the temp table.